# Add Dataset Table Adapter to ApplicationEvents.vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, dataset, tableadapter

I have some code in my ApplicationEvent.vb to handle command line params and then run some procedures based on whatever param was input at cmd.

The problem is that I need to execute a procedure that has a dataset table adapter in it.

Obviously as I want it to run in batch mode I can't have a table adapter as they are GUI based (or at least I think they are) so I am getting this error:

`'V_SyncStatusTableAdapter' is not a member of 'AppName.My.MyApplication'`

For this code:

```
If Me.V_SyncStatusTableAdapter.GetData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
      drSyncResult = Me.V_SyncStatusTableAdapter.GetData.Rows(0)
```

Now this is obviously because the table adapter hasn't and AFAIK can't be put into the ApplicationEvents.vb file.

I know that the dataset is called: `dsetWorkingTables` and the table is called `v_SyncStatus`. I have tried:

`dsetWorkingTablesTableAdapters.v_SyncStatusTableAdapter.GetData` but that gives:

`reference to non shared member requires object reference`

So my question is:

**How do I get data from a dataset in the ApplicationEvents.vb file?**

Comment: @John - I have found if I add: frmSynchronise <- the class which the code originates in it removes the errors - why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to referene your table adapter against the form class it exists in.   Even with forms, you can still access methods on the forms as you will, what you want to avoid is form.Show() which will case the form to appear on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Is your table adapter in a separate project from your Application Events? If so, you need to reference that project.

Table Adapters are not just for GUI, they can be used in batch or console apps as well.